# What path I should choose to study game programming or become an expert game designer?

Tags: game-engine

I have a bachelor in computer science. And have been busy doing security research these years. I am also going to start my master soon which has also a theme of security.

I have good programming skills, C/C++/CUDA/Python...

Recently, I have noticed that, mainly from when I was a game geek, I love being around computer games. And between jobs in the game market, Game Designer and Game Programmer are the most interesting for me. Because, I believe that I have skills and enough imagination for being a designer and also the skills to be a good game programmer.

I personally prefer to continue an academic path. But I am a little *big* confused about what to do...

Is the academia the right way? If yes, where I can find the right institution?
 Should I start learning more things? Should I start painting and working on 3D software and computer graphics? Is there a path that you have already went through and you are feeling successful now?

I'll be really thankful.
Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be better suited in programmers.SO, but I'll answer it here, anyway.

If you want to know what path you should take, the easiest and best way to find out is to look at the job requirements for your desired job at your dream company. This means, if you want to be a game programmer/designer, check out the job boards at EA, Blizzard, Microsoft, Valve, Trion, etc. and see what they want from you. Keep in mind that you'll probably need to pretty specifically decide what you want to do. Being a designer (concept art, 3D modeling, etc) takes a different skill set than being a programmer (polygon collision logic, randomization logic, etc) takes a different skill set than being an engineer (physics engines, graphic card interfacing, etc).

That way, not only will you know what kind of degree they're looking for, but also what they want in terms of experience, internships, and other skillsets. As an added bonus, you'll already be on track to land a killer internship with them.

Comment: Reading the job opportunity section of the vendor websites helped me greatly! Thanks